# How to write the age of an old object

Tags: word-choice

Given: On display in the National Museum are more than 5,000 works of art, ranging from the 6th to the 13th Century.

Q: How old are the works of art displayed in the National Museum?

- A: 1.The works of art displayed in the National Museum are from about 800 to 1500 years old.
- A: 2. The works of art displayed in the National Museum are from about 8 to 15 centuries old.
- A: 3. The works of art displayed in the National Museum are hundreds of years old.
- A: 4. The works of art displayed in the National Museum are between 800 and 1500 years old.

Are these four answers to the question grammatical and natural?

Comment: All of these are correct grammatically, however as pointed out 1 & 2 are redundant in using "from aboout"

Answer (score 1):

3 and 4 are good, 1 and 2 have the same problem. "From" and "about" are redundant, they fill the same purpose. You should use about, to express the ages are an estimate, but from would work in the same meaning as 4.